# Simple SQL query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Languages` which stores the languages every person stored in `Persons` table is able to talk, then I have a table called `Homework` which stores all the homework every person has to do, but related to a language. I'm able to select the homework person 1 has to do for language 1 (Left join), but also would like to be able to select in the same query the language person 1 is able to talk. Could someone give me a hint how to accomplish that?  A left join to Languages will screw the results as will mess with languages on Homework table.

Languages and Persons are Many2One, the same goes for Homework and Persons.

That works but gets screw when I add a second `left join`:

```
SELECT p.id, l.id, h.id
FROM Persons AS p
LEFT JOIN Homework AS h ON h.person_id = p.id
#LEFT JOIN Languages AS l ON l.person_id = p.id #Screws the result multipliying by the number of available languages
WHERE p.id = 1
AND h.language_id = 1
```

I would like to combine the above query and the following:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM languages
 WHERE person_id=1
```

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail, how does a second join mess with your result? An example of what you get and what you would like to get would be nice.

Comment: Could you try and outline the table you would like to end up with

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for the answer. I can't provide you results as that's a simplified problem i have from a more complex one. The thing is, if you have 3 languages in Languages table, then the last left join will make the results be 3 times "big".

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find?

```
Person | Language | Homework 
------------------------------
Bob | English | 
Bob | French | 
Bob | Spanish | Geography

James | English |
James | French | History
James | Spanish |
```

Using this...

```
SELECT p.id, l.id, h.id
FROM Persons AS p

LEFT JOIN Languages AS l ON l.person_id = p.id 

LEFT JOIN Homework AS h ON h.language_id = l.id
    And h.person_id = p.id
```

Or

```
Person | Language | Homework 
------------------------------
Bob | Spanish | Geography
James | French | History
```

Which I believe is what has already been suggested

UPDATE : This should now give you the person with all the languages but only show homeworks matching the language you want

```
SELECT p.id, l.id, h.id
FROM Persons AS p

LEFT JOIN Languages AS l ON l.person_id = p.id 

LEFT JOIN Homework AS h ON h.language_id = l.id
    And h.person_id = p.id
    And h.language_id = 1
```

Comment: That query will work fine, but i also would like to append something like: AND h.language_id = X so it shows only the homework belonging to language = x but also will show me the available languages linked to a person. Thx a lot :)

Comment: Additional criteria added that should limit the homeworks returned based on languages.